# Read folders in folder one by one

Tags: python-3.x, path

I am trying to read folders in one folder, and analyse the daten in these folders. My idea is to write two loop: one to choose the folder, one to analyse daten in the chosen folder. But i don't know how can i write the new path with iterate variable. line3 [of this snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r0mLo.jpg) is my problem.

Thank you for any input.

Comment: Please paste your code into the question, and use the `{}` button in the editor while selecting your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only want to get the folders inside another folder (subfolders) and aren't interested in other files that could be in the root folder you could use:

```
import os

path = '...'

for file_folder in os.listdir(path):
    path1 =  os.path.join(path, file_folder)
    if os.path.isdir(path1):
        print(path1)
        # do something
```

or

```
import glob

path = '...'
for folder in glob.glob(f'{path}/*/'):
    # do something
```

Answer (score 0):

In line number two & three from the image, you have written:

```
for file_folder in os.listdir(path):
    path1 = 'path' + '\' + str(file_folder)
```

file_folder is like a temporary variable holding folder name value for a particular **iteration**.

It should instead be:

```
for file_folder in os.listdir(path):
    path1 = 'path' + '\\' + file_folder
```

Comment: thanks for ur attention. I tried ur code. But there is a Message " SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal". What does that mean?